# MSVC error C2753 caused by bug (partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++17, template-specialization

The following code compiles successfully on Clang 15.0.7 and GCC 12.2.0 compilers using C++17:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t s = 0u>
struct A: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, sizeof(T)>: std::true_type {};

static_assert(A<int, sizeof(int)>::value);
```

But MSVC 19.35.32215 fails with:

```
error C2753: 'A<T,sizeof(T)>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
error C2607: static assertion failed
```

I have a workaround already:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
struct B: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct B<T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(T)>>: std::true_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t s = 0u>
using A = B<T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, s>>;

static_assert(A<int, sizeof(int)>::value);
```

And I know that a "Non-type template argument cannot specialize a template parameter whose type depends on a parameter of the specialization", but in the first code sample the type is always `std::size_t` and does not depend on the parameter. Only the value of the non-type template argument depends on the parameter.

Is this allowed according to the standard? Is this another MSVC bug?